# Long table in latex overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I've got this piece of code for a long table in overleaf which doesn't overrun onto the next page - it kind of gets lost.

Does anyone know how to carry over the table onto the next available page?

It is a double columned article but I want the table to span over a few pages...

Here is the code:

```
\begin{longtable*}[ht]
\centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccccccccccccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{p{6.93em}}{\textbf{Target name}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.715em}}{\textbf{RA \newline{}(h m s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.855em}}{\textbf{Dec \newline{}(}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.855em}}{\textbf{Spk 22\newline{}(Jy)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{2.93em}}{\textbf{Spk 23\newline{}(Jy)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.355em}}{\textbf{Sint 22\newline{}(Jy km s\^-1)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.215em}}{\textbf{Sint 23\newline{}(Jy km s\^-1)}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{RMS 22}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.215em}}{\textbf{RMS 23}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.285em}}{\textbf{Size 22\newline{}(")}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.355em}}{\textbf{Size 23\newline{}(")}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3em}}{\textbf{beam size 22\newline{}(")}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{3.645em}}{\textbf{beam size 23\newline{}(")}} \\
    \hline

    G0.092-0.663 & 17:48:26 & -29:12:18.858 & 0.255 & -     & 0.269 & -     & 0.006 & -     & 48.504 & -     & 46.966 & - \\
    G0.212-0.001 & 17:46:07 & -28:45:30.833 & 0.358 & -     & 0.536 & -     & 0.008 & -     & 61.79 & -     & 49.333 & - \\
    G0.315-0.201 & 17:47:07 & -28:46:03.643 & 0.209 & -     & 0.41  & -     & 0.009 & -     & 72.33 & -     & 50.474 & - \\
    G0.376+0.040 & 17:46:21 & -28:35:39.631 & 1.149 & -     & 1.135 & -     & 0.016 & -     & 47.918 & -     & 48.244 & - \\
    G0.546-0.852 & 17:50:14 & -28:54:29.701 & 9.247 & -     & 9.94  & -     & 0.144 & -     & 52.022 & -     & 50.087 & - \\
    G0.645-0.042 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:05.143 & 10.13 & 2.784 & 13.77 & 4.041 & 0.354 & 0.116 & 57.114 & 53.568 & 48.859 & 44.516 \\
    G0.647-0.055 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:05.553 & 6.127 & 1.661 & 7.954 & 2.34  & 0.101 & 0.05  & 57.203 & 54.3  & 50.084 & 45.904 \\
    G0.651-0.049 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:05.084 & 12.88 & 3.742 & 16.82 & 5.228 & 0.591 & 0.153 & 57.192 & 52.965 & 49.825 & 44.355 \\
    G0.657-0.041 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:05.127 & 26.47 & 7.821 & 33.01 & 9.769 & 0.402 & 0.379 & 57.287 & 51.069 & 51.228 & 45.11 \\
    G0.665-0.036 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:04.068 & 31.07 & 10.11 & 38.04 & 12.88 & 1.99  & 0.531 & 52.522 & 50.431 & 46.945 & 44.064 \\
    G0.666-0.029 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:04.415 & 26.37 & 8.988 & 28.68 & 11.21 & 1.14  & 0.25  & 52.48 & 48.806 & 50.123 & 43.145 \\
    G0.667-0.034 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:46.432 & 21.39 & 10.26 & 556.3 & 12.09 & 4.46  & 0.546 & 776.93 & 48.1  & 49.929 & 43.77 \\
    G0.672-0.031 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:04.315 & 28    & 9.768 & 30.23 & 11.24 & 1.26  & 0.49  & 51.561 & 46.97 & 49.618 & 43.07 \\
    G0.673-0.029 & 17:47:20 & -28:23:04.293 & 27.53 & 9.009 & 28.93 & 10.64 & 0.874 & 0.491 & 51.089 & 47.864 & 50.017 & 43.583 \\
    G0.695-0.038 & 17:47:19 & -28:22:43.817 & 7.545 & -     & 1323  & -     & 1.58  & -     & 4673.2 & -     & 49.266 & - \\
    G2.143+0.009 & 17:50:36 & -27:05:47.452 & 0.017 & 3.454 & 0.021 & 4.139 & 0.001 & 0.079 & 79.26 & 61.561 & 73.185 & 55.609 \\
    G2.615+0.134 & 17:51:12 & -26:37:40.263 & 0.447 & 87.3  & 0.591 & 110.4 & 0.012 & 1.73  & 84.038 & 63.621 & 76.059 & 56.775 \\
    G3.312-0.399 & 17:54:51 & -26:18:15.050 & 0.008 & 1.221 & 0.01  & 1.722 & 0     & 0.094 & 82.594 & 67.273 & 77.049 & 57.015 \\
    G3.442-0.348 & 17:54:56 & -26:09:47.442 & 0.245 & 47.33 & 0.254 & 49.19 & 0.003 & 0.569 & 77.95 & 57.589 & 77.181 & 56.648 \\
    G3.910+0.001 & 17:54:39 & -25:34:44.695 & 0.242 & 46.29 & 0.26  & 50.41 & 0.004 & 0.869 & 80.488 & 60.316 & 76.01 & 56.892 \\
    G4.676+0.276 & 17:55:19 & -24:46:29.882 & 0.026 & 5.074 & 0.026 & 5.064 & 0.001 & 0.102 & 75.92 & 55.781 & 74.395 & 55.804 \\
    G5.630-0.294 & 17:59:34 & -24:14:20.501 & 0.008 & 1.36  & 0.021 & 2.904 & 0     & 0.124 & 106.4 & 82.08 & 73.14 & 56.89 \\
    G5.885-0.393 & 18:00:30 & -24:04:01.373 & 20.5  & 4169  & 21.31 & 4296  & 0.192 & 72.4  & 71.544 & 58.115 & 70.753 & 57.4 \\
    G11.936-0.150 & 18:12:11 & -18:41:29.566 & 0.005 & 0.003 & 0.007 & 0.004 & 0     & 0     & 66.075 & 64.934 & 58.194 & 54.835 \\
    G11.936-0.616 & 18:14:01 & -18:53:23.656 & 1.153 & 1.011 & 1.459 & 1.278 & 0.023 & 0.018 & 57.082 & 58.658 & 51.947 & 53.648 \\
    G12.202-0.120 & 18:13:01 & -18:17:04.723 & 0.074 & 0.101 & 539.3 & 0.114 & 0.018 & 0.004 & 11002 & 57.528 & 57.263 & 54.91 \\
    G13.657-0.599 & 18:17:22 & -17:23:38.810 & 0.005 & 0.004 & 0.006 & 0.005 & 0     & 0     & 61.323 & 65.59 & 51.721 & 54.085 \\
    G14.101+0.087 & 18:15:45 & -16:38:51.469 & 0.052 & 0.045 & 0.082 & 0.067 & 0.004 & 0.002 & 70.627 & 69.749 & 52.99 & 54.53 \\
    G14.991-0.121 & 18:18:17 & -15:58:23.038 & 0.007 & 0.006 & 0.012 & 0.009 & 0     & 0     & 68.696 & 65.497 & 53.355 & 54.541 \\
    G18.460-0.004 & 18:24:36 & -12:51:05.154 & 0.417 & 0.371 & 0.429 & 0.385 & 0.007 & 0.007 & 59.124 & 54.841 & 58.854 & 54.423 \\
    G18.667+0.025 & 18:24:53 & -12:39:19.773 & 0.006 & 0.005 & 0.006 & 0.005 & 0     & 0     & 59.571 & 55.716 & 59.566 & 55.919 \\
    G19.486+0.151 & 18:26:04 & -11:52:33.274 & 0.078 & 0.06  & 0.127 & 0.097 & 0.003 & 0.003 & 74.798 & 69.165 & 59.512 & 55.931 \\
    G19.496+0.115 & 18:26:04 & -11:52:33.043 & 0.085 & 0.071 & 0.138 & 0.1   & 0.003 & 0.001 & 75.323 & 66.647 & 60.09 & 56.648 \\
    G320.424+0.089 & 15:09:40 & -57:59:41.289 & 0.022 & 0.019 & 0.03  & 0.023 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 80.375 & 69.779 & 66.729 & 61.782 \\
    G326.476+0.695 & 15:43:17 & -54:07:14.165 & 0.003 & 0.003 & 0.004 & 0.004 & 0     & 0     & 68.651 & 66.035 & 62.254 & 59.269 \\
    G327.402+0.445 & 15:49:19 & -53:45:14.208 & 0.137 & 0.125 & 0.141 & 0.128 & 0.002 & 0.001 & 62.605 & 59.497 & 61.819 & 58.925 \\
    G331.132-0.244 & 16:10:59 & -51:50:25.883 & 0.08  & 0.109 & 0.172 & 0.289 & 0.007 & 0.012 & 101.02 & 111.58 & 61.672 & 58.583 \\
    G331.442-0.187 & 16:12:13 & -51:35:11.186 & 0.039 & 0.058 & 0.039 & 0.06  & 0     & 0     & 62.335 & 59.784 & 62.049 & 58.638 \\
    G331.542-0.066 & 16:12:09 & -51:25:47.773 & 0.188 & 0.269 & 0.203 & 0.295 & 0.006 & 0.005 & 64.533 & 60.704 & 62.365 & 58.011 \\
    G331.543-0.066 & 16:12:09 & -51:25:48.013 & 0.19  & 0.266 & 0.209 & 0.299 & 0.008 & 0.005 & 64.879 & 61.641 & 62.06 & 58.114 \\
    G331.556-0.121 & 16:12:27 & -51:27:31.454 & 0.093 & 0.142 & 0.189 & 0.228 & 0.006 & 0.007 & 86.191 & 72.363 & 61.896 & 58.667 \\
    G332.295+2.280 & 16:05:44 & -49:10:47.318 & 0.001 & -     & 0.002 & -     & 0     & -     & 66.456 & -     & 60.832 & - \\
    G332.560-0.148 & 16:17:02 & -50:47:04.259 & 0.007 & 0.009 & 0.014 & 0.014 & 0     & 0     & 86.436 & 71.212 & 60.373 & 56.835 \\
    G332.826-0.549 & 16:20:11 & -50:53:15.061 & 2.368 & 3.527 & 2.621 & 3.975 & 0.046 & 0.067 & 63.785 & 62.716 & 60.882 & 59.386 \\
    G333.029-0.063 & 16:18:57 & -50:23:54.456 & 0.017 & -     & 0.018 & -     & 0     & -     & 63.669 & -     & 62.015 & - \\
    G333.121-0.434 & 16:21:03 & -50:35:12.761 & 1.104 & 1.522 & 1.063 & 1.469 & 0.054 & 0.052 & 60.851 & 57.098 & 62.311 & 58.535 \\
    G333.126-0.440 & 16:21:03 & -50:35:12.986 & 1.267 & 1.829 & 1.225 & 1.797 & 0.038 & 0.046 & 61.371 & 58.091 & 63.124 & 59.336 \\
    G333.128-0.440 & 16:21:03 & -50:35:13.061 & 1.344 & 1.971 & 1.32  & 1.971 & 0.041 & 0.054 & 61.816 & 58.7  & 62.819 & 59.077 \\
    G333.163-0.101 & 16:19:42 & -50:19:53.554 & 0.057 & 0.083 & 0.066 & 0.103 & 0.001 & 0.002 & 66.789 & 64.554 & 62.442 & 58.874 \\
    G333.184-0.091 & 16:19:42 & -50:19:53.219 & 0.038 & 0.028 & 0.047 & 0.033 & 0.001 & 0.001 & 66.794 & 60.877 & 61.475 & 56.862 \\
    G336.983-0.183 & 16:36:12 & -47:37:58.182 & 0.031 & 0.047 & 0.031 & 0.049 & 0     & 0.001 & 61.846 & 58.603 & 61.836 & 57.512 \\
    G336.994-0.027 & 16:35:32 & -47:31:15.373 & 0.059 & 0.083 & 0.087 & 0.127 & 0.002 & 0.003 & 74.848 & 69.98 & 61.73 & 57.196 \\
    G338.926+0.634 & 16:40:15 & -45:39:03.094 & 0.193 & 0.167 & 0.21  & 0.182 & 0.007 & 0.006 & 62.245 & 60.517 & 60.651 & 58.625 \\
    G339.980-0.538 & 16:49:15 & -45:36:32.199 & 0.111 & 0.099 & 0.116 & 0.104 & 0.004 & 0.004 & 60.69 & 58.093 & 60.309 & 57.489 \\
    G341.218-0.212 & 16:52:18 & -44:26:52.899 & 0.621 & -     & 0.63  & -     & 0.007 & -     & 51.042 & -     & 50.724 & - \\
    G341.973+0.233 & 16:53:05 & -43:35:10.274 & 0.18  & 0.172 & 0.18  & 0.178 & 0.006 & 0.004 & 48.298 & 46.728 & 48.224 & 45.568 \\
    G342.368+0.140 & 16:54:49 & -43:20:00.499 & 0.057 & -     & 0.059 & -     & 0.001 & -     & 50.349 & -     & 49.345 & - \\
    G342.484+0.183 & 16:55:02 & -43:13:00.281 & 0.137 & -     & 0.136 & -     & 0.004 & -     & 48.878 & -     & 48.942 & - \\
    G343.354-0.067 & 16:59:04 & -42:41:37.834 & 0.157 & 0.124 & 0.287 & 0.249 & 0.007 & 0.009 & 67.658 & 64.04 & 50.03 & 44.741 \\
    G343.756-0.163 & 17:00:50 & -42:26:09.128 & 0.34  & -     & 0.346 & -     & 0.005 & -     & 50.395 & -     & 49.899 & - \\
    G343.929+0.125 & 17:00:11 & -42:07:19.229 & 0.17  & 0.166 & 0.159 & 0.177 & 0.004 & 0.005 & 48.777 & 45.468 & 50.432 & 44.031 \\
    G344.227-0.569 & 17:04:08 & -42:19:53.536 & 0.509 & 0.284 & 0.639 & 0.339 & 0.014 & 0.007 & 54.762 & 46.897 & 48.891 & 42.866 \\
    G344.419+0.044 & 17:02:09 & -41:46:44.419 & 1.841 & 1.661 & 3.443 & 3.177 & 0.082 & 0.091 & 65.9  & 60.636 & 48.325 & 43.671 \\
    G344.421+0.045 & 17:02:09 & -41:46:44.552 & 2.111 & 1.887 & 3.743 & 3.695 & 0.086 & 0.111 & 66.417 & 63.022 & 49.636 & 44.892 \\
    G344.581-0.024 & 17:02:58 & -41:41:54.000 & 3.549 & -     & 3.579 & -     & 0.053 & -     & 48.653 & -     & 48.482 & - \\
    G345.003-0.223 & 17:05:11 & -41:29:07.075 & 1.104 & 1.094 & 1.159 & 1.155 & 0.018 & 0.017 & 50.406 & 44.957 & 49.314 & 43.756 \\
    G345.003-0.224 & 17:05:11 & -41:29:06.983 & 1.085 & 1.078 & 1.136 & 1.143 & 0.017 & 0.02  & 48.561 & 44.516 & 47.376 & 43.169 \\
    G345.010+1.792 & 16:56:48 & -40:14:25.452 & 1.103 & 1.072 & 1.288 & 1.144 & 0.063 & 0.026 & 52.805 & 43.402 & 48.508 & 41.853 \\
    G345.012+1.797 & 16:56:48 & -40:14:25.301 & 0.992 & 1.044 & 1.083 & 1.1   & 0.032 & 0.032 & 49.815 & 42.611 & 47.961 & 41.551 \\
    G345.407-0.952 & 17:09:35 & -41:35:55.707 & 2.285 & 2.228 & 2.492 & 2.647 & 0.047 & 0.06  & 50.389 & 44.958 & 48.174 & 40.804 \\
    G345.487+0.314 & 17:04:28 & -40:46:23.751 & 6.011 & 5.832 & 7.82  & 7.699 & 0.146 & 0.178 & 55.574 & 50.757 & 48.747 & 44.058 \\
    G346.522+0.085 & 17:08:43 & -40:05:09.911 & 0.547 & 0.478 & 1.021 & 1.059 & 0.034 & 0.036 & 67.846 & 67.629 & 49.014 & 45.65 \\
    G347.628+0.149 & 17:11:51 & -39:09:29.490 & 0.67  & 0.661 & 0.667 & 0.659 & 0.022 & 0.024 & 50.619 & 44.984 & 50.385 & 44.777 \\
    G347.863+0.019 & 17:13:09 & -39:02:28.959 & 0.55  & 0.524 & 0.601 & 0.597 & 0.018 & 0.012 & 49.792 & 46.438 & 47.693 & 43.314 \\
    G348.654+0.244 & 17:14:32 & -38:16:16.479 & 0.084 & -     & 0.094 & -     & 0.005 & -     & 54.519 & -     & 51.415 & - \\
    G348.884+0.096 & 17:15:50 & -38:10:13.223 & 0.038 & -     & 0.038 & -     & 0.001 & -     & 47.524 & -     & 47.539 & - \\
    G348.892-0.180 & 17:17:00 & -38:19:26.694 & 0.253 & 0.351 & 0.37  & 0.517 & 0.013 & 0.019 & 57.904 & 57.799 & 47.747 & 47.133 \\
    G349.092+0.105 & 17:16:25 & -37:59:45.777 & 0.097 & -     & 0.093 & -     & 0.003 & -     & 46.649 & -     & 47.791 & - \\
    G349.092+0.106 & 17:16:25 & -37:59:45.798 & 0.096 & -     & 0.092 & -     & 0.003 & -     & 45.449 & -     & 46.39 & - \\
    G350.015+0.433 & 17:17:45 & -37:03:12.571 & 0.241 & 0.325 & 0.245 & 0.344 & 0.003 & 0.004 & 49.836 & 48.301 & 49.285 & 46.858 \\
    G350.105+0.083 & 17:19:27 & -37:11:01.403 & 0.455 & 0.592 & 1.254 & 1.287 & 0.039 & 0.032 & 80.864 & 69.604 & 47.46 & 47.393 \\
    G350.116+0.220 & 17:18:48 & -37:06:25.533 & 0.037 & 0.043 & 0.041 & 0.045 & 0.001 & 0.002 & 49.627 & 50.086 & 46.704 & 48.072 \\
    G350.189+0.003 & 17:19:57 & -37:09:33.888 & 0.094 & 0.109 & 0.187 & 0.206 & 0.005 & 0.006 & 67.381 & 64.606 & 47.612 & 47.131 \\
    G350.340+0.141 & 17:19:53 & -36:57:20.901 & 0.025 & -     & 0.033 & -     & 0.002 & -     & 55.3  & -     & 48.342 & - \\
    G350.686-0.491 & 17:23:29 & -37:01:48.999 & 0.061 & -     & 0.059 & -     & 0.003 & -     & 46.863 & -     & 47.29 & - \\
    G351.161+0.697 & 17:19:57 & -35:57:53.166 & 0.529 & -     & 0.556 & -     & 0.007 & -     & 49.622 & -     & 48.214 & - \\
    G351.242+0.670 & 17:20:18 & -35:54:41.720 & 5.901 & -     & 5.329 & -     & 0.281 & -     & 46.939 & -     & 48.972 & - \\
    G351.251+0.652 & 17:20:18 & -35:54:44.427 & 1.392 & -     & 15.18 & -     & 0.367 & -     & 295.91 & -     & 47.443 & - \\
    G351.417+0.645 & 17:20:53 & -35:46:59.583 & 4.897 & 4.265 & 7.938 & 4.858 & 0.091 & 0.096 & 59.374 & 48.652 & 45.677 & 45.778 \\
    G351.417+0.646 & 17:20:53 & -35:46:59.465 & 4.979 & 4.547 & 7.934 & 5.23  & 0.076 & 0.089 & 59.696 & 47.103 & 46.322 & 43.899 \\
    G351.445+0.660 & 17:20:55 & -35:45:03.666 & 0.942 & -     & 1.098 & -     & 0.049 & -     & 49.886 & -     & 46.1  & - \\
    G351.581-0.353 & 17:25:25 & -36:12:45.223 & 5.639 & 1.361 & 5.639 & 1.312 & 0.194 & 0.082 & 56.867 & 51.752 & 56.899 & 53.199 \\
    G351.611+0.172 & 17:23:23 & -35:53:43.636 & 0.535 & -     & 0.919 & -     & 0.017 & -     & 60.79 & -     & 46.491 & - \\
    G351.775-0.536 & 17:26:43 & -36:09:18.174 & 2.371 & 0.37  & 3.453 & 0.417 & 0.158 & 0.009 & 71.092 & 46.518 & 56.516 & 43.353 \\
    G352.517-0.155 & 17:27:11 & -35:19:31.720 & 0.571 & 0.092 & 0.539 & 0.477 & 0.024 & 0.02  & 55.589 & 129.11 & 56.385 & 49.519 \\
    G352.525-0.158 & 17:27:14 & -35:18:06.618 & 0.318 & -     & 0.352 & -     & 0.019 & -     & 58.186 & -     & 56.126 & - \\
    G352.624-1.077 & 17:31:15 & -35:44:47.173 & 3.053 & -     & 3.064 & -     & 0.061 & -     & 54.362 & -     & 54.367 & - \\
    G352.630-1.067 & 17:31:15 & -35:44:47.623 & 1.582 & -     & 1.637 & -     & 0.061 & -     & 55.915 & -     & 55.12 & - \\
    G352.855-0.201 & 17:28:18 & -35:04:09.701 & 0.095 & 0.151 & 1.18  & 0.369 & 0.017 & 0.016 & 328.22 & 77.097 & 47.484 & 44.641 \\
    G353.216-0.249 & 17:29:28 & -34:47:48.663 & 0.01  & -     & 0.07  & -     & 0.003 & -     & 187.22 & -     & 47.978 & - \\
    G353.273+0.641 & 17:26:02 & -34:15:15.070 & 2.556 & -     & 2.588 & -     & 0.059 & -     & 55.961 & -     & 55.589 & - \\
    G353.363-0.166 & 17:29:31 & -34:37:41.263 & 1.096 & 0.457 & 1.281 & 0.548 & 0.044 & 0.019 & 60.324 & 50.123 & 55.752 & 46.224 \\
    G353.378+0.438 & 17:27:11 & -34:16:34.991 & 0.185 & -     & 0.206 & -     & 0.004 & -     & 48.369 & -     & 45.237 & - \\
    G353.410-0.360 & 17:30:26 & -34:41:25.563 & 0.073 & 0.197 & 49.76 & 35.85 & 0.052 & 0.091 & 1453.8 & 1587.8 & 46.856 & 44.871 \\
    G354.206-0.038 & 17:31:15 & -33:51:16.103 & 0.141 & 0.225 & 0.149 & 0.24  & 0.005 & 0.01  & 49.528 & 46.705 & 48.55 & 45.271 \\
    G354.701+0.299 & 17:31:15 & -33:14:13.136 & 0.072 & 0.108 & 1.054 & 1.692 & 0.015 & 0.028 & 450.39 & 415.08 & 48.104 & 44.593 \\
    G354.724+0.300 & 17:31:16 & -33:14:05.456 & 0.511 & 0.737 & 0.556 & 0.797 & 0.008 & 0.017 & 48.47 & 48.813 & 46.726 & 47.227 \\
    G355.343+0.148 & 17:33:29 & -32:47:58.008 & 1.625 & 0.499 & 1.711 & 0.651 & 0.026 & 0.03  & 53.689 & 53.809 & 52.304 & 47.273 \\
    G355.344+0.147 & 17:33:29 & -32:47:57.793 & 1.707 & 0.64  & 1.814 & 0.706 & 0.027 & 0.009 & 52.055 & 47.779 & 50.577 & 45.55 \\
    G355.346+0.149 & 17:33:29 & -32:47:57.490 & 1.353 & 0.666 & 1.469 & 0.74  & 0.027 & 0.011 & 52.514 & 49.384 & 50.555 & 46.841 \\
    G357.558-0.321 & 17:40:57 & -31:10:59.253 & 1.171 & 0.047 & 1.22  & 1.849 & 0.035 & 0.012 & 50.951 & 804.03 & 49.843 & 46.819 \\
    G357.559-0.321 & 17:40:57 & -31:10:59.607 & 1.35  & 0.073 & 1.403 & 0.074 & 0.024 & 0.005 & 51.911 & 45.598 & 51.009 & 45.153 \\
    G357.965-0.164 & 17:41:20 & -30:45:06.762 & 5.115 & -     & 5.246 & -     & 0.087 & -     & 50.411 & -     & 49.82 & - \\
    G357.967-0.163 & 17:41:20 & -30:45:06.524 & 5.191 & -     & 5.273 & -     & 0.115 & -     & 50.858 & -     & 50.493 & - \\
    G358.386-0.483 & 17:43:38 & -30:33:49.576 & 0.663 & 0.329 & 0.661 & 0.336 & 0.019 & 0.01  & 50.648 & 45.8  & 50.736 & 45.325 \\
    G359.138+0.031 & 17:43:26 & -29:39:17.170 & 5.458 & -     & 5.617 & -     & 0.083 & -     & 51.124 & -     & 50.368 & - \\
    G359.615-0.243 & 17:45:39 & -29:23:30.487 & 1.014 & -     & 1.027 & -     & 0.02  & -     & 49.035 & -     & 48.674 & - \\
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{longtable*}%
```

I'm new to latex so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: A tabularx environment requires at least  one `X` column type to be useful. However, it doesn't break across pages. To break a tabularx across pages, load the `xltabular` package and use its eponymous environment. Last point: a longtable does not float, so using `[ht]` is irrelevant.

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Which font, and which font size? How wide and how tall is the text block? Alternatively, do please reveal which paper size you employ (A4? US Letter? something else?) and how wide the margins are.

Answer (score -1):

Here'ss some code I've used that facilitates multiple pages.

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{longtable}
% Note: It may be necessary to compile the document several times to get a multi-page table to line up properly
{\tiny
\singlespacing
\begin{longtable}{lllp{4cm}llllp{3cm}}
\caption{Clusters Derived from Model Predictions}

\textbf{True Label} & \textbf{Cluster} & \textbf{SOC} & \textbf{Occupation Title} & \textbf{True Label} & \textbf{Cluster} & \textbf{SOC} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Occupation   Title}} \\
\hline
\endhead
%
0 & 0 & 111011 & Chief Executives & 336 & 6 & 292054 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Respiratory Therapy Technicians} \\
1 & 0 & 111021 & General and Operations Managers & 425 & 6 & 393021 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Motion Picture Projectionists} \\
6 & 0 & 113011 & Administrative Services Managers & 508 & 6 & 435071 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Shipping, Receiving, and Traffic   Clerks} \\
[ADDITIONAL ROWS HERE]
\end{longtable} 
\footnotesize{    Notes: }
}
```